# npm install zmq issue

Tags: node.js, npm, zeromq

I am doing npm install zmq but stuck in strange error, please see below

C:\Users\Administrator>npm install zmq

**MSBUILD : error MSB4132: The tools version "2.0" is unrecognized. Available too
ls versions are "4.0".**

gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe`
 failed with exit code: 1

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)

gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)

googled but with no luck.
this is a fresh install on windows server 2012. and zmq is already installed using windows msi installer, but i want to use zmq under nodejs so doing npm.
i think msbuild is failing as node is assuming version 2 of .net framework, however installed .net version is 4. 
can any one please guide me how to solve the issue - thanks

regards
zishan

Comment: I believe that what you need is Visual Studio (VC++ compilers), not .NET Framework (C#!).

Answer (score 1):

right, thanks Gustav, I solved it  by installing visual studio 2012.
first I changed the .net version from 4 to 2 by going to server manager, than I got another error where it says the system requires .net v2 sdk then i installed the sdk and finally visual studio 2012 of 5 gb.
problem solved but i am amazed why we have to install 5 gb of vs to make zmq work, can it not be done only by linking the required dll or library, why it requires whole bunch of vb files!
any ways its done.

Answer (score 0):

"npm install zmq" requires Visual Studio 2013 or less, Python 2.7.x

If you have multiple versions of Visual Studio, run this script to make 2013 as default :-
set gyp_msvs_version=2013

or you can try this other official package - "zeromq"

with zeromq, you don't have to worry about all the binaries. It comes with pre-build binaries for win(32/64), Linux(64), OS X/ Darwin(64 bit)

"npm install zeromq"