# I can't install any node js packages that need to be compiled

Tags: node.js, windows-7-x64

Any node js package that needs to be compiled fails on my system.
I am using Windows 7 64 bit SP1.

[Log of error](http://pastebin.com/77Aec2bS)

Edit: I tried installing VS2008EXP but only the error has changed.

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Have you tried this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160838/npm-install-zmq-issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot install node modules that require compilation on Windows 7 x64/VS2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012)